# Self-signed certificate used when wrapping sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cryptography

I'm trying to use a self-signed x509 certificate generated using the cryptography module in an ssl handshake.  I'm generating the cert and key to PEM files as prescribed in [the documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#creating-a-self-signed-certificate) and writing them to files using the following function:

```
def write_key_and_cert(self, certname="cert.pem", keyname="key.pem"):
    with open(certname, "wb") as f:
        f.write(self.cert.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))
    with open(keyname, "wb") as f:

    f.write(self.private_key.private_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                                           format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
                                           encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(b"passphrase"),),)
```

The problem arises during the wrapping of the socket, the server is unable to use the certfile and keyfile, causing a hang.  I believe it is due to the keyfile being encrypted (the ssl wrapping isn't decrypting the keyfile).  Is there a way to use the cryptography module generated certfile/keyfile and, if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved by creating the context and specifying the password when loading the cert chain:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=self.certfile, keyfile=self.keyfile, password=b"passphrase")
```

This lets the ssl module do the decrypting of the keyfile and loading properly.